# How to print binary content of bytes pointed by a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, printf

I have a pointer returned from malloc. Which points to first byte of allocated size. For EX:

```
  void* p=malloc(34);
```

How to print the binary values contained in those 34 bytes. ?

Comment: char *p=(char*)malloc()...try with this it may work...

Comment: Nothing of interest is contained in these bytes until you write to them. When malloc returns, the pointer points to garbage until you do some writes into that memory.

Comment: @vinod Don't cast `malloc` (especially to a `char`)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I think markdown is affecting @vinod's comment, the italicised text runs right between where you'd expect two asterisks: `char *p = (char *) malloc()`... still, one shouldn't cast the result of malloc.

Comment: Not sure he want really to print in binary, but rather "see" what's in that allocated memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want this :

```
int i ;
void* p=malloc(34);

for (i = 0; i < 34; i++)
{
  unsigned char c = ((char*)p)[i] ;
  printf ("%02x ", c) ;
}
```

It doesn't print in binary (010011011) but in hexadecimal, but that's probably what you want.

But as stated in the comments you will get garbage values.